Adjoint of the covariant derivative of a field?
Let's call $D$ the covariant derivative, $T$ the transposition of a field and $*$ its complex conjugate, so $T*$ is the "adjoint".
Is: $$(D_{\mu}\Phi)^{T*} (D_{\mu}\Phi)=D^{\mu}\Phi^*D_{\mu}\Phi \ \ ?$$

Can you write explicitly which covariant derivative you are using?

Let s ignore covariant derivative and consider partial derivative if you prefer

Since you defined the adjoint as $\dagger \equiv T\circ \ast = \ast \circ T$, it does not act on the partial derivative. I think that telling you a bit more about the notion of "adjoint" will confuse you more than it will enlighten you. For now, consider simply that your adjoint acts only on the fields.

What's the transpose of a derivative? Are you taking the gradient of a vector field and swapping the indices w.r.t. the gradient? If $\Phi$ is a scalar field the question is meaningless to me, if it's a tensor field with rank $\ge 2$ you should tell which pair of indices are you swapping

@basic $\Phi$ is most likely a multiplet of scalars.

I don't master my question, so I will learn more and revist the question. Sorry.

@MathieuKrisztian good take. A bit of background, description of the field or the problem/application you're dealing with, or any other detail you think as useful, may help as well

The transpose of a partial derivative is minus that partial derivative, because of the minus sign from integration by parts.
